# PHP file_get_contents "authorization required"

Tags: php, authentication

I'm trying to fetch a file from a server that requires authentication. I have the following PHP code:

```
//Import categories
$url = "http://$username:$password@www.example.com";
$categoriesXML = file_get_contents($url);

var_dump($url . " > " . $categoriesXML);
return;
```

The output of this page is merely: string(22) "Authorization Required". I also tried with:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password"))));

$url = "http://www.example.com";
$categoriesXML = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($categoriesXML);
return;
```

I tried with cURL as well with the following code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($output);
return;
```

The cURL returns a 301 code in the $info and the $output is empty. I'm a PHP/server newbie, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: With file_get_contents, try replacing `@` with `%40` or even better use `urlencode()`.

Comment: Try correct username and password?

Comment: 301 - set `curl` to follow redirections using `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` set to true.

Comment: With %40 I get this:
"A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Couldn't resolve host name".

I'm pretty sure the username and password are correct.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld, it worked but it still says "Authorization required" :(

Comment: @Sagito: Are you sure that your auth is done using `Authorization` and not one of the IIS alternatives, that your password is correct, and that you're using the right kind of HTTP auth..?

Comment: @SébastienRenauld, the remote server is not mine, but I think they use IIS... I didn't know that IIS had other alternatives, is there a particular way to access it? :/

Comment: @Sagito: any chance of having an URL to test? IIS itself does not do it "wrong", it just is overly strict on the auth method (hence why I asked about whether you are sure that digest is what you want)

Comment: @Sagito: try `CURLAUTH_BASIC` or `CURLAUTH_ANY` and try again.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld it worked! :D Thank you so much! :D Want to post that as an answer so that I can mark it as correct? :)

Comment: @Sagito: Done. No problem :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP's problem was due to choosing the wrong HTTP auth mechanism. Setting `CURLOPT_AUTH` to `CURLAUTH_BASIC` or the more permissive `CURLAUTH_ANY` proved to solve the problem.